# Creating graph of spectrogram in android using musicg library

Tags: java, android, audio

I am attempting to create a spectrogram visualisation in Android. I use the android device to record sound in .PCM format and then convert this to .WAV so that it can be analysed using the musicg library https://code.google.com/p/musicg/.

Using musicg I can create a spectrogram of the recorded .WAV and from this spectrogram I can extract the frequency time domain data as a double[][].

What I am trying to work out next is how to visualise this data in Android. Any help would be appreciated.

Following user3161880 answer, I have tried the following but I am not getting anything drawn to screen. I can draw a circle as shown in user3161880 answer. Any ideas why this wouldn't work?

```
private static class SpectrogramView extends View {
        private Paint paint = new Paint();
        private double [][] data;

        public SpectrogramView(Context context, double [][] data) {
            super(context);
            this.data = data;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);

            if (data != null) {
                paint.setStrokeWidth(1);
                canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
                int width = data.length;
                int height = data[0].length;
                for(int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
                    for(int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
                        int value;
                        value = 255 - (int)(data[i][j] * 255);
                        paint.setColor(value<<16|value<<8|value|255<<24);
                        canvas.drawPoint(i, height-1-j, paint);
                    }
                }

            } else {
                System.err.println("Data Corrupt");
            }

            //draw circle
            /*paint.setColor(Color.RED);
            canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);
            canvas.drawCircle(100.0f, 100.0f, 50.0f, paint);*/
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An improved answer than in my original post.

```
private static class SpectrogramView extends View {
    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    private Bitmap bmp;

    public SpectrogramView(Context context, double [][] data) {
        super(context);

        if (data != null) {
            paint.setStrokeWidth(1);
            int width = data.length;
            int height = data[0].length;

        int[] arrayCol = new int[width*height];
        int counter = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                int value;
                int color;
                value = 255 - (int)(data[j][i] * 255);
                color = (value<<16|value<<8|value|255<<24);
                arrayCol[counter] = color;
                counter ++;
            }
        }
        bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(arrayCol, width, height, Config.ARGB_8888);

        } else {
            System.err.println("Data Corrupt");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 100, paint);
    }
}
```

This will improve performance by creating a bitmap before drawing to canvas.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to show the still spectrogram of the prerecorded audio, a simple `View` would suffice for you. You can override `onDraw` method of the view. Here you will get access to the `Canvas` on which the background will be drawn.

What remains is your display logic, which maps `double` to color and time-frequency grid to x-y co-ordinates of the canvas.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new MyView(this));
    }

    private static class MyView extends View {

        Paint paint = new Paint();

        public MyView(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);

            // draw circle
            paint.setColor(Color.RED);
            canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);
            canvas.drawCircle(100.f, 100.f, 50.f, paint);
        }

    }
}
```