# How to generate a Spectrogram from double[][]

Tags: java, android, audio

I have a double[][] that comes from an audio file and I want to make it a spectrogram and then display it in a Bitmap.

I've done some tests but they're not conclusive.

The code to generate the image from double[][]:

```
public Bitmap testSpectrum(Context context, double[][] data) {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    Bitmap bmp;

    if (data != null) {
        paint.setStrokeWidth(1);
        int width = data.length;
        int height = data[0].length;

        int[] arrayCol = new int[width * height];
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                int value;
                int color;
                value = 255 - (int) (data[j][i] * 255);
                color = (value << 16 | value << 8 | value | 255 << 24);
                arrayCol[counter] = color;
                counter++;
            }
        }

        return bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(arrayCol, width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    } else {
        System.err.println("Data Corrupt");
    }

    return null;
}
```

I get double[][] from the library https://github.com/loisaidasam/musicg

```
// create a wave object
    com.musicg.wave.Wave wave = new com.musicg.wave.Wave(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.wav2));

    // Spectrogram
    int fftSampleSize = 1024;
    int overlapFactor = 0;
    Spectrogram spectrogram = new Spectrogram(wave, fftSampleSize, overlapFactor);

    Bitmap bSpect = testSpectrum(this, spectrogram.getNormalizedSpectrogramData());
```

The function that generates the double[][]

```
private void buildSpectrogram(){

    short[] amplitudes=wave.getSampleAmplitudes();
    int numSamples = amplitudes.length;

    int pointer=0;
    // overlapping
    if (overlapFactor>1){
        int numOverlappedSamples=numSamples*overlapFactor;
        int backSamples=fftSampleSize*(overlapFactor-1)/overlapFactor;
        int fftSampleSize_1=fftSampleSize-1;
        short[] overlapAmp= new short[numOverlappedSamples];
        pointer=0;
        for (int i=0; i<amplitudes.length; i++){
            overlapAmp[pointer++]=amplitudes[i];
            if (pointer%fftSampleSize==fftSampleSize_1){
                // overlap
                i-=backSamples;
            }
        }
        numSamples=numOverlappedSamples;
        amplitudes=overlapAmp;
    }
    // end overlapping

    numFrames=numSamples/fftSampleSize;
    framesPerSecond=(int)(numFrames/wave.length()); 

    // set signals for fft
    WindowFunction window = new WindowFunction();
    window.setWindowType("HAMMING");
    double[] win=window.generate(fftSampleSize);

    double[][] signals=new double[numFrames][];
    for(int f=0; f<numFrames; f++) {
        signals[f]=new double[fftSampleSize];
        int startSample=f*fftSampleSize;
        for (int n=0; n<fftSampleSize; n++){
            signals[f][n]=amplitudes[startSample+n]*win[n];                         
        }
    }
    // end set signals for fft

    absoluteSpectrogram=new double[numFrames][];
    // for each frame in signals, do fft on it
    FastFourierTransform fft = new FastFourierTransform();
    for (int i=0; i<numFrames; i++){            
        absoluteSpectrogram[i]=fft.getMagnitudes(signals[i]);
    }

    if (absoluteSpectrogram.length>0){

        numFrequencyUnit=absoluteSpectrogram[0].length;
        unitFrequency=(double)wave.getWaveHeader().getSampleRate()/2/numFrequencyUnit;  // frequency could be caught within the half of nSamples according to Nyquist theory

        // normalization of absoultSpectrogram
        spectrogram=new double[numFrames][numFrequencyUnit];

        // set max and min amplitudes
        double maxAmp=Double.MIN_VALUE;
        double minAmp=Double.MAX_VALUE; 
        for (int i=0; i<numFrames; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<numFrequencyUnit; j++){
                if (absoluteSpectrogram[i][j]>maxAmp){
                    maxAmp=absoluteSpectrogram[i][j];
                }
                else if(absoluteSpectrogram[i][j]<minAmp){
                    minAmp=absoluteSpectrogram[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
        // end set max and min amplitudes

        // normalization
        // avoiding divided by zero 
        double minValidAmp=0.00000000001F;
        if (minAmp==0){
            minAmp=minValidAmp;
        }

        double diff=Math.log10(maxAmp/minAmp);  // perceptual difference
        for (int i=0; i<numFrames; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<numFrequencyUnit; j++){
                if (absoluteSpectrogram[i][j]<minValidAmp){
                    spectrogram[i][j]=0;
                }
                else{
                    spectrogram[i][j]=(Math.log10(absoluteSpectrogram[i][j]/minAmp))/diff;
                }
            }
        }
        // end normalization
    }
}
```

The desired result:
[image]

The result I get:
[image]

I'm thinking about a buffer problem for the incomplete image and I haven't looked at the colors yet.

Comment: "comes from an audio file" - seems more like an image file.... anyway I would start with a simpler and known data sample (I wonder how this could produce an image with code since all components (rgb) are equal)

Comment: This comes from a WAV file, the result is from a software. The sound is at the end of the page. https://www.web3.lu/spectrogram-speech-processing/, I'm still missing a piece. I have the beginning and the end but not the middle. This always returns an image of 255px height. I don't know if it comes from the function to generate the spectrogram or if it comes from the double[][]

Comment: and I can't see how this is "generating a [Spectrogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrogram)" - it is more like displaying an image

Comment: I use the library https://github.com/loisaidasam/musicg and for generating bitmap https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24679849/creating-graph-of-spectrogram-in-android-using-musicg-library

Comment: It seems, that data[0] always has a length of 255, that could be an error. How do you read in the sound? Where/how is the double[][] created?
The missing colors come obviously from the fact that you create an image where the R, G and B components all have the same value - which will create a greyscale image. You would like to use a palette image probably...

Comment: I don't know that libraries but from the image it seems more like that is a problem with interpretation of input or resulting FFT-Data (one half array being inverted) Also check the sample size....

Comment: I added the function used by musicg to generate the double[][]

Comment: I had a look at the com.musicg.wave.extension.Spectrogram class, and to me it seems, that you have to use the constructor public Spectrogram(Wave wave, int fftSampleSize, int overlapFactor) and set the parameters fftSampleSize and overlapFactor to correct values (which I don't know). I would say that fftSampleSize is four times the resulting arrays second dimension (see the class com.musicg.dsp.FastFourierTransform for that and also have the indicator that 1024 is the default for fftSampleSize and 1024/4 = 256)

Comment: Thanks, You found some things, the values used were ftSampleSize = 1024 and overlapFactor = 1
By setting fftSampleSize = 1024*2 and overlapFactor = 1, I get a slightly more complete picture.
When I do fftSampleSize = 1024*2 and overlapFactor = fftSampleSize/4 (or other), I get the error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError https://imgur.com/a/lBLGN6Y